# How can I run commands in a bash script prefixed with sudo, but based on a flag?

Tags: bash, sudo

My use case is that docker on macOS does not require sudo or root access since it uses a protected security model with some HyperVisor system (details off-topic here), while on Linux based systems with real Linux kernel and cgroups, docker requires `sudo` or otherwise `root` access to run containers and commands.

I'd like to write a *fairly* portable script that properly detects the environment and either runs all the docker commands with `sudo` if needed, or without it if not.

**What is the best way to achieve this?**

I suppose one solution would be to just use `docker` straight up in the script, and linux users will need to run `sudo ./script.sh`, while macOS users could just run `./script.sh`, but then all the contained commands will run under root -- e.g. mkdir, creation of files, etc. It doesn't seem to be the most clean way.

Example what I'm looking for:

```
$sudo_or_not docker run -d nginx
$sudo_or_not docker ps | grep nginx
```

or maybe

```
run_docker_command("docker run -d nginx")
run_docker_command("docker ps | grep nginx")
```

But I'm not sure how to get something like that working in bash. Assume I already have a variable such as `$IS_MAC_OS` that is either `0` or `1`, so detecting the OS is not important here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux systems, access to Docker is typically gated behind a `docker` group,  which has write access to the Docker sockets:

```
% stat /var/run/docker.sock
  File: /var/run/docker.sock
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   socket
Device: 17h/23d Inode: 831         Links: 1
Access: (0660/srw-rw----)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (  999/  docker)
Access: 2019-12-03 15:41:42.633241981 +0900
Modify: 2019-11-28 15:49:03.877925150 +0900
Change: 2019-11-28 15:49:03.877925150 +0900
 Birth: -
```

Users who are members of that group won't need `sudo` to run `docker` commands.

---

However, you can use a wrapper function like so:

```
if [[ $IS_MAC_OS = 1 ]]
then
    sudo_or_not () {
        "$@"  # just run the arguments
    }
else
    sudo_or_not () {
        sudo "$@"  # run the arguments with sudo
    }
fi

sudo_or_not docker run foo/bar
```

Or just wrap `docker` itself:

```
if [[ $IS_MAC_OS = 1 ]]
then
    docker () {
        command docker "$@"  # just run the actual docker command with arguments
    }
else
    docker () {
        sudo docker "$@"  # run docker with sudo
    }
fi

docker run foo/bar
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's awesome! Yes I knew about tweaking the group so I can run docker commands without sudo, however it's a fair security risk since that essentially means any process running under just "user" mode obtain root access (if malicious) due to the way docker and cgroups work on Linux, if they invoked a specific docker command.